# Min and Max of a list of Associations

Tags: list-manipulation, associations

I am trying to find the minimum values for all elements in a list of associations, below is an example

```
x = {<|"a"-> 4, "b"->9, "c"->15|>, <|"a"->21, "b"->11, "c"->1|>, <|"a"->12, "b"->3, "c"->21|>}
```

> Required output for Min
>   {<|"a"-> 2, "b"->3, "c"->1|>}
>
> Required output for Max
>   {<|"a"-> 21, "b"->11, "c"->15|>}

My attempt
for Max: `MaximalBy[Values]@x`
Result: {<|"a" -> 21, "b" -> 11, "c" -> 1|>}

for Min: `MinimalBy[Values]@x`
Result: {<|"a" -> 4, "b" -> 9, "c" -> 15|>}

Is there an elegant way to achieve this result?

Comment: I don't get it. How is the key `a` getting the value `2`? That value does not appear for `a` in any of the associations. Similarly, why is the value of `c` not equal to `21` in the maximal result?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

How about

```
a = {
    <|"a" -> 4, "b" -> 9, "c" -> 15|>,
    <|"a" -> 21, "b" -> 11, "c" -> 1|>,
    <|"a" -> 12, "b" -> 3, "c" -> 21|>
};

Merge[a, Min]

(*<|"a" -> 4, "b" -> 3, "c" -> 1|>*)

Merge[a, Max]

(*<|"a" -> 21, "b" -> 11, "c" -> 21|>*)
```

*EDIT*

Improved, as per Kuba's suggestion.

Answer (score 7):

```
Random`Private`MapThreadMin[x]
Random`Private`MapThreadMax[x]
```

> <|"a" -> 4, "b" -> 3, "c" -> 1|>
>
> <|"a" -> 21, "b" -> 11, "c" -> 21|>

Comment: is there any list out there for these "hidden" commands? Or do you happen to have a favourite list that you can share with us?

Comment: A good try is always `?*`*` ;) Honestly, I learned this trick very recently from Carl Woll. Some other good place to look for such things is [What are some useful undocumented Mathematica functions?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/805/what-are-some-useful-undocumented-mathematica-functions)

Comment: Thanks, I am checking the link right now :)

Answer (score 3):

```
x = 
 {<|"a" ->  4, "b" ->  9, "c" -> 15|>, 
  <|"a" -> 21, "b" -> 11, "c" ->  1|>, 
  <|"a" -> 12, "b" ->  3, "c" -> 21|>};
```

Using `MinMax` and `ArrayReduce` (new in 12.2)

Columns

```
AssociationThread[{"a", "b", "c"} -> ArrayReduce[MinMax, Values[x], 1]]
```

<|"a" -> {4, 21}, "b" -> {3, 11}, "c" -> {1, 21}|>

Rows

```
AssociationThread[{"a", "b", "c"} -> ArrayReduce[MinMax, Values[x], 2]]
```

<|"a" -> {4, 15}, "b" -> {1, 21}, "c" -> {3, 21}|>

Answer (score 2):

You may use [`Query`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Query.html) and [`MinMax`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MinMax.html).

With `x` as in OP.

```
Query[Transpose /* Map[MinMax]]@x
```

> ```
> <|"a" -> {4, 21}, "b" -> {3, 11}, "c" -> {1, 21}|>
> ```

You can produce a more descriptive result with [`AssociationThread`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AssociationThread.html).

```
res = Query[Transpose /* Map[AssociationThread[{"Min", "Max"}, MinMax@#] &]]@x
```

> ```
> <|"a" -> <|"Min" -> 4, "Max" -> 21|>, 
>   "b" -> <|"Min" -> 3, "Max" -> 11|>, 
>   "c" -> <|"Min" -> 1, "Max" -> 21|>|>
> ```

Which you can then access by [`Key`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Key.html) with [`Association`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html)'s syntax sugar.

```
res["a", "Max"]
```

> ```
> 21
> ```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

```
x = {<|"a" -> 4, "b" -> 9, "c" -> 15|>,
     <|"a" -> 21, "b" -> 11, "c" -> 1|>,
     <|"a" -> 12, "b" -> 3, "c" -> 21|>};
```

Using `Merge`, `Sort` and `Part`:

```
Function[a, #[[{1, -1}]] &@Sort@a] /@ Merge[x, Identity]

(*<|"a" -> {4, 21}, "b" -> {3, 11}, "c" -> {1, 21}|>*)
```

Or using `AssociationThread`:

```
f = Function[a, #[[{1, -1}]] &@Sort@a];
```

For Columns:

```
f /@ AssociationThread[Keys@# -> Values@#] &@Merge[x, Identity]

(*<|"a" -> {4, 21}, "b" -> {3, 11}, "c" -> {1, 21}|>*)
```

For Rows:

```
f /@ AssociationThread[Keys@# -> Transpose@Values@#] &@Merge[x, Identity]

(*<|"a" -> {4, 15}, "b" -> {1, 21}, "c" -> {3, 21}|>*)
```